# How do I activate/use django-mptt on an database with data?

Tags: python, django, django-1.7, django-mptt

I have an existing database with an `offices` table. It has the following fields:

```
id
lvl
parent_id
name
code
```

I have a Django (1.7) model that looks like:

```
class Office(models.Model):
    id          = models.IntegerField( primary_key=True )
    lvl         = models.IntegerField( blank=True, null=False )
    parent      = models.ForeignKey( 'self', null=True)
    name        = models.TextField( blank=True)
    code        = models.TextField( blank=True)

    class Meta:
        managed  = False
        db_table = 'offices'

    def __str__(self):
        return "(" + self.code + ") " + self.name + ", level " + str(self.lvl)
```

In its current form, calling `someoffice.parent` works properly and returns the parent. However, I need to be able to call `someoffice.children()` and get back the children of an individual parent node.

This seems like a good use case for [django-mptt](http://django-mptt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). However, I can't figure out how to use `django-mptt` on the existing model and database table without Django throwing errors about missing migrations. I'm more than happy to scrap the model and/or replace it with something else. What I do not want to do is to toss out the existing table, unless I can easily do it once and not have to struggle with this anymore.

How can I work with the existing database table to implement `django-mptt`?

---

**Edit**: There are several other convenience functions in `django-mptt` I'd also would like to use, so I'm looking for advice on how to either implement `django-mptt` with the existing table, to modify the table *in situ* so that I can use `django-mptt` without migrations, or to create a new table and then load my data into it. Ideally, I can alter the existing table and then use `django-mptt` without needing to run a Django migration.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for mptt if you just want to get children for a parent. That functionality is built in to Django: given an instance of Office called `my_office`, you can get its children with `my_office.office_set.all()`.

You probably want to give the reverse accessor a better name, which you can do by modifying the field definition:

```
parent      = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name='children')
```

Now you can do `my_office.children.all()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. I wasn't comprehensive in the question, so I'll edit it. There are other convenience functions in `django-mptt` that I might like to use in templates, etc., so I'm looking for a way to implement that with the table I have and/or advice about whether I should create a new table and migrate data into it, etc.